# Call ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource and ID3D11DeviceContext::Map for each frame?

Tags: c++, directx-11

I'm trying to create an application that uses DirectX 11 to output to a swap chain and a bytemap at the same time. I call `ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource` to copy from the backbuffer texture into a staging texture and `ID3D11DeviceContext::Map` to map the staging texture to memory to read from it. Works fine with my single frame test.

Do I need to call both methods for each frame or once before rendering any frames?

Comment: "read-back" from the GPU is almost always slow, so you should try to minimize it as much as possible. If you are rendering the scene yourself, you should probably render to a texture instead of the swapchain which you can then copy rather than having to deal with the swapchain backbuffer cycle.

Comment: from what I can see `IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer` returns a pointer to the backbuffer interface, which is a `ID3D11Texture2D` Resource. I then copy that into my previously created staging texture using `ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource`

My questions is do I need to do that for every frame that I want to render or only once?

Comment: After ``Present`` there's a new buffer object with a swapchain. If the scene changes each frame, then you need to copy each frame.

Answer (score 0):

After calling `IDXGISwapChain::Present` there's a new buffer object with a swapchain. If the scene changes each frame, the resource needs to be copied each frame. (Explained by Chuck in comment above)